# On derivation of curvature formulas

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I can't figure out the idea behind the following part of the derivation of curvature formulas;

We let $M$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $N$ be it's Gauss map. Moreover we consider a point $p\in M$ and local parametrisation $X$ such that $X(0)=p$.

Given this, there is a matrix  $A$ of $-dN: T_{p}M \rightarrow T_{p}M$ with respect to the basis $X_{u},X_{v}$.

So far I understand things, now however, two matrix valued maps $DX=[X_{u},X_{v}]$ and $DN=[N_{u},N_{v}]$ are introduced from $U$ which is the domain of the parametrisation which satisfy ,

$-DN=DX A$

I dont understand this last equality.

The complete outline can be found on pages 46-47 in,

http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Gauss.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we understand where everything is coming from, this makes a lot more sense. Thus, I will try to explain the intuition behind each of these.

$[DX]: U\to \mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}$ is a map which goes from the 2 dimensional domain $U$ to two different vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which together form the tangent space at that point on the manifold.

$[DN]: U\to \mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}$ is a map which goes from the 2 dimensional domain $U$ to two different vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which describe the changes in the normal vector as we travel along our domain $U$ before pushing it into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$A: U\to \mathbb{R}^2$: I believe this is the function you are misunderstanding. As described in the linked PDF, it does not go from $T_pM\to T_pM$. It is still the matrix which represents how the normal changes, but instead, it is in the original domain, and is pushed into $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the function $X$ so we have
$$Ax=y \implies -dN(X(x)) = X(y)$$
Now, it should be easy to see that $-[DN]=[DX]\circ A$, as they are both performing the same operation. The introduction of the matrix $A$ just allows us to see that we can view this mapping of the derivative of the normal as a linear transformation in $U$ before mapping it to $\mathbb{R}^3$ via $X$.

Comment: I am thinking of $[DX]$ as a fixed matrix and it does acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ not $U$ and $A$ which is a matrix of a linear map on the tanget space acts on the coordinate space w.r.t to the basis i.e $\mathbb{R}^2$ aswell. $A$ does not act on $U$ but on  $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which $U$ is a subset of)

Comment: As I see it at the moment $-[DN]$ should also be such a matrix and thus a map  $\mathbb{R}^2$ to  $\mathbb{R}^3$ while  $-[DX] \circ A$ maps into $T_{p}M$

Comment: I fixed the issue with $A$'s range. As for $[DX]$ and $[DN]$, it states in your linked document that they are matrix valued maps from $U\to \mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}$. So, the equality sign here is actually an equality of functions going from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 2}$.

Comment: Another thing which you might be confused about is that both $N_u$ and $N_v$ are perpendicular to $N$, so they can be said to lie in the tangent space.

Comment: I think of [DN] as the Jacobi matrix of N i.e dN. Letting [1,0] and [0,1] act on $[DN]$ we get the elements of the tanget space

Comment: That's a good way to think of it, except it's a mapping from $U$ to those matrices, representing the change in normal at each point. Makes sense now?